# Update Many if exists , otherwise create for each LeadId that doesn't exists a new Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the Schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const EightWeekGamePlanSchema = new Schema({
  Week: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  LeadId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  PackageId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  BusinessName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  PhoneNumberMasque: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  City: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  Rooms: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  LeadStartDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  LeadEndDate: {
    type: Date
  },

  TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType: {
    // incresed by 1 every time it's claimed
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType: {
    // Stays fixed
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  Status: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },

  InsertDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = EightWeekGamePlan = mongoose.model(
  "eightweekgameplan",
  EightWeekGamePlanSchema
);
```

I'm trying the write a pretty complex query : updates multiple documents by given number in `howManyClaims` , if their `LeadID` appears in a given array `winnerLeads` AND their `TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType` property equals the given `groupTarget` :

```
router.post("/add-claims-to-group", auth, async (req, res) => {
    const { howManyClaims, groupTarget, winnerLeads, week } = req.body;
    EightWeekGamePlan.updateMany(
        {
          LeadId: {
            $in: winnerLeads
          },
          TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType: groupTarget
        },
        { $inc: { TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType: howManyClaims } },
        { multi: true },
        (err, writeResult) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log(writeResult);
          }
        }
      );
}
```

Otherwise , do some kind of a `Create` : take one of the existing `EightWeekGamePlan` documents that belong to the `LeadID` , duplicate it and set its `TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType` property with `howManyClaims`.

Is it possible to combine both Update and Create actions in one query ?

Comment: @srinivasy: Thanks for the help , works partially , in case of the insert the code inserts a new document with only 4 properties `(LeadId , TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType, Week , _id)` , but I to insert all the properties , not only 4.Is it possible to tell Mongo to run a function when inserting document and then handle the creation of the document in that function ?

Comment: it will only insert the fields what you pass in either filter or in update object, So it can’t insert all fields or fields which are not passed, So do you mean to insert default values if you do not pass a field? Try to check ‘{setOnInsert : }’ but even there you need to pass the fields

Comment: @srinivasy: Your answer is good , so I'm accepting it.I'll try to manage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your query, since you're doing `.updateMany()`, you don't have to do `{ multi: true }`. Anyway usually you can do upsert using `{upset: true}`, but it would ideally create a new document based on filter criteria with update fields from input query only if no match is found in DB. But since here we're have a list (`$in`) in filter criteria it might not work normally, try this :

```
let winnerLeads = [1, 2, 3, 31, 5]
let groupTarget = 1
let howManyClaims = 2
let bulkArr = []
for (i of winnerLeads) {
    bulkArr.push({
        updateOne: {
            "filter": {
                LeadId: i,
                TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType: groupTarget
            },
            // If you wanted it to be incremented rather than replace the field, then try `$inc` instead of `$set`.
            "update": { $set: { TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType: howManyClaims } },
            "upsert": true
        }
    })
}
db.EightWeekGamePlan.bulkWrite(bulkArr);
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06eb8f400289966e00fac2"),
    "LeadId" : 1,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1.0,
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06eb98400289966e00fb88"),
    "LeadId" : 2,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1.0,
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06eba0400289966e00fc47"),
    "LeadId" : 3,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 0,
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 11
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06ebac400289966e00fd4b"),
    "LeadId" : 4,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1,
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 11
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06ecef400289966e01273a"),
    "LeadId" : 5,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1.0,
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06eb8f400289966e00fac2"),
    "LeadId" : 1,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 2.0,
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06eb98400289966e00fb88"),
    "LeadId" : 2,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 2.0,
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06eba0400289966e00fc47"),
    "LeadId" : 3,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 0,
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 11
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06ebac400289966e00fd4b"),
    "LeadId" : 4,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1,
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 11
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06ecef400289966e01273a"),
    "LeadId" : 5,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 2,
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e071eb1400289966e0597a0"),
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1.0,
    "LeadId" : 3.0,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 2.0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e071e62400289966e059168"),
    "TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1.0,
    "LeadId" : 31.0,
    "TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType" : 2.0
}
```

Basically bulkWrite doesn't return any documents except write result, you can verify in DB for update operation result, Also from the above result `6` got insert as `LeadId : 3 + TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType" : 1.0`(So `LeadId:3` is duplicated) combination is not present in DB & `7` got inserted as `LeadId : 31` is not present in DB, Remaining `1`,`2`,`5`'s `TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType` got updated.

**Ref :** [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html)