# Update or Upsert multiple document mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am working on a project using mongodb database, and I want to update or upsert multiple document.

So here is what I want to do:

```
if (you received an array of id ) 
{
    create a verify condition which checks if there is a document for each id and respect the dateFin condition
}
else if (you received one id)
{
    create a verify condition which checks if there is a document equal the id and respect the dateFin condition
}
```

then check if there is a document, then update it, else create it either you got an array or one id

```
 if (Array.isArray(req.body.user) === true)
                verify = {
                    idUser: { $in: req.body.user.map(id => { return ObjectId(id) }) },
                    dateFin: { $gt: moment().utc(1).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') }
                }
            else verify = 
                  { 
                    idUser: ObjectId(req.body.user), 
                    dateFin: { $gt: moment().utc(1).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') } 
                  }
            db.collection("paiement").updateMany(verify,
                    {
                        $set: {
                            dateFin: moment(req.body.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'),
                            paiementType: "offre",
                            abonnement: req.body.abonnement,
                            dateInsert: moment().utc(1).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'),
                        },
                    },
                    { upsert: true },
                    (err, document) => {
                        if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);
                        console.log(err);
                        console.log(document.result);
                    })
        }
```

but it works with one id, and not with multiple ids, Thank you if there is any one can help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Many if exists , otherwise create for each LeadId that doesn't exists a new Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59506916/update-many-if-exists-otherwise-create-for-each-leadid-that-doesnt-exists-a-n)

Comment: this one use the iteration 'for' wich take alot of time, and i don't want that because it's hard to the server, (imagine i am workin with 1000 id...)

Comment: Ok as far as I know for upserts on multiple documents bulkwrite is the only option, not sure if there is another..